# JAVA - REGEX - Don't match only whitespaces

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to build a regular expression that doesn't allow only whitespaces, but, for example, does allow

```
"    aaaaa    "
"      aaaaa"
"aaaaaa       "
```

The string's lenght should be {1,150}.

I'm trying to use

```
^(?=.\\S).{1,20}$
```

...but it doesn't work for the input of

```
"    aaaaaa"
```

Comment: do you want to allow white spaces in the match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?!\s+$).{1,150}$
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a regular expression to match between 1 and 150 non-whitespace characaters that are optionally sandwiched with whitespace:

`^\s*\S{1,150}\s*$`

Comment: OP wants to allow white spaces also.

Comment: Edited to allow for "sandwiching" whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the contents and length separately. Apply a regex to check if the string contains at least one non-whitespace character at any position:

```
\S
```

And then check the length with:

```
myString.length() >= 1 && myString.length() <= 150
```

Answer (score 0):

`^(.*[^\s].*){1,150}$`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/90ugyEA7agbSxT_m)

Comment: This doesn't actually enforce the upper limit.